# How to structure MySQL schema for user settings that can have an arbitrary order

Tags: mysql, schema

In our application, we currently have a list of about 150 user settings. These were previously hard-coded. The hardcoded "table" looked like this:

```
[ old settings ]
----------------
setting_key    (string)
setting_label  (string)
checked        (0 / 1)
```

Each user had an entry in mongo that was essentially a giant array containing these values. Since the user can choose the order in which the settings appear, the order that the user had set was preserved by updating the array structure. Also, if the user changed the `setting_label`, it would be updated for their entry for that `setting_key`. This just allowed the user to rename labels.

We are currently trying to refactor all these user settings to get away from hard-coding giant settings structures and having to update every single piece of information when the user might only change one setting. To do this, we set up the following MySQL schema:

```
[ settings ]  --> the master list of settings that each user has
------------
setting_id        (int, auto-increment, primary key)
setting_key       (varchar)
setting_label     (varchar)

[ user_settings ] --> custom settings that override the default setting_id
-----------------
user_setting_id    (int, auto-increment, primary key)
user_id            (int)
setting_id         (int, foreign key references settings.setting_id)
user_label         (varchar)
```

This works until we realized that we still have to preserve the order of the settings somehow. And allow the user to change that order.

We thought about making a `settings_order` table like this:

```
[ settings_order ] --> user_id has settings in a specific order
------------------- 
user_id       (int)
setting_id    (int, foreign key referencing settings.setting_id)
order_number  (int)
```

The problem is, if I have 150 settings by default, that means `order_number` would go between `0` and `150`, and would seemingly be hard-coded. And if a user moved `order_number` `150` to `order_number` `1`, then all `order_number`'s after `1` would have to be shifted down to account for this. Overall it seems a bit challenging to maintain.

Can anyone help me understand what the best type of schema for this would be? Or any ideas for a way to preserve order for a list of settings?

Comment: Store the settings order in a JSON string in a single column for each user.

Comment: instead of add table, add `order_number` COLUMN to user_settings table

Answer (score 1):

This will boil down to how your software needs to interact with the data.  And as usual in these scenarios inquiring about the "best" way, the answer is "It depends!  Details matter."  Here are three options, and which you pick should depend on your usage pattern needs:

- The "proper" method considering an RDBMS and a schema might indeed attach an ordering value, or ranking, to each row, either through an auxiliary table or an extra column.  This allows you to implement constraints like "no two rows can have equal ranking (`UNIQUE(...)`)", and you can have the DB's optimizer and caching mechanisms save you some details in your application code.  On the other hand, it implies a number of write operations whenever a user reorders their settings.  And then the standard engineering "epsilon" question: does performance matter?  Certainly, it is inefficient to rewrite all of those rows, but if each user is only doing it maybe once or twice, does it actually present a problem?
- Meanwhile, you can try another suggestion (@SloanThrasher beat us to the punch!) which merely updates a single text row (call it CSV or JSON or ...) with the ordering whenever needed.  This moves the burden from the schema definition to your application code, however, to make sure you never leave stale or incorrect references (e.g., setting is removed, setting updated, new setting created).
- Another option which I have seen implemented to great effect is to have an ordering column or auxiliary table -- complete with ACID details handled by the schema -- but the ranking is in effect a sorted binary tree.  In that case, the ranking was continuously and heavily updated by users, so the extra burden incurred by the application code surrounding the SELECT statement was deemed worth it.

You measures, pays your monies, makes your choices, and measures agains.  Good lucks!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I do have a question though. What is the difference between the first solution (column-based) and your third solution? It sounds like both leverage the schema and an order? The thing that confuses me is the sorted binary tree in MySQL. Are you saying that on the application level, we implemented a sorted binary tree of numbers? Or on the actual MySQL level? Or are there any examples of this?

Comment: The last bullet references an "actual schema-backed binary tree."  The details are too complex for a comment and more in-depth than the "give me suggestions" nature of your original question.  [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) should give you the bump you need.  However, before diving down this rabbit hole, I suggest considering the _actual_ usage.  In aggregate, do users reorder settings enough to be a problem?  You can always refactor after it becomes an actual problem.  **Don't** pre-optimize.